# Whats wrong with this ternary expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to toggle between `display: block;` and `display: none;`.

```
($('#menu').css('display') = "block") ? $('#menu').css('display', 'none') : $('#menu').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Side note:  Why are you doing this?  Wouldn't `$('#menu').toggle()` be better here?

Comment: @RocketHazmat My expression is inside $('#menuButton').on('click', function(){

Comment: So?  What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Put Rocket's code inside of your event handler then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to try to re-invent the wheel.  jQuery already has a method that does this for you: [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
$('#menu').toggle();
```

Answer (score 9):

Change `=` to `==`

```
($('#menu').css('display') == "block") ? $('#menu').css('display', 'none') : $('#menu').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: This is one reason why people use the unnatural-looking `("block" == $('#menu').css('display'))`.

Comment: @EricJablow: But `$('#menu').css('display') = 'block'` would've thown an error just like `'block' = $('#menu').css('display')` would've.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - But with a fixed value like "block" on the LHS, people are unlikely to put in `=` and more likely to put in the `==` correctly.

Comment: This is only useful when one opens the console before questioning.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a minor alteration by using `:visible` instead of explicitly checking for a particular `display` value.

```
$('#menu').css('display', $('#menu').is(':visible') ? 'none' : 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` instead of `==` for comparison.

Try this instead:

```
(function(e) {e.display = e.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';})(document.getElementById('menu').style);
```